Why is TypeScript not throwing a compile-time error when constructor is not used here?
These are the types:
class Foo {}
class Bar<T> {
    value: T;

    constructor(val: T) {
        this.value = val;
    }
}
type Baz<T> = Foo | Bar<T>;

and this the wrong instantiation:
let foo:Baz<string> = Foo;
if (foo instanceof Foo) {
    ..do something...
} else {
    ..something else..
}

Playground
Of course, in hindsight, I should have used:
let foo:Baz<string> = new Foo();

but sometimes that may be difficult to catch at first sight. Why is the TypeScript compiler accepting the above code instead of throwing a compiler error? Is there a way to write the types that would be more helpful?
I tried adding an empty constructor to Foo, and making it a type instead of a class, but it didn't work. Maybe I'm missing an interface?

let foo = Foo is valid, you're assigning the "type" in essence. foo instanceof Foo would fail however for that case. Perhaps some type of linting check for "using a type as a value" would be helpful here, but I'm not familiar with the exact term. The statements on their own are perfectly valid, it's the combination that presents with issues.

@jonsharpe sorry, fixed typos

@Rogue, I missed the type hint, added now

Basically a class is an object, so it's assignable to a variable, and the variable then can be used as a constructor, or can access static members

let foo:Baz<string> = Foo shouldn't be valid, you're not assigning a Baz<string> but rather Foo (a function!)

@HairyHandKerchief23 but a class is not an instance of Bar<string>, look at the type hint I added to foo

@Rogue: exactly, shouldn't be valid! but typescript is compiling it fine

Mind you in many setups linting and compilation are separate. There may be a compiler error but no linting error and vice-versa. Follow @jonrsharpe 's advice to create a minimal, reproducible example (something we can copy/paste verbatim and see the issue on our machines. No pseudocode).

@Rogue fixed one more typo and put a playground link; see: no compilation errors

Empty classes have empty instance types, and almost everything is assignable to {}: see FAQ entry. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer (or more likely find an existing question this duplicates). If not, what's missing?

@jcalz any way to write Foo so that it's empty but its class cannot be used as an instance of Baz? only an instance should be allowed by the compiler, not the class itself

TypeScript is structurally typed, so there's very little point to an empty class. If it had any properties, you'd see "Type 'typeof Foo' is not assignable to type 'Baz'.(2322) input.tsx(15, 23): Did you mean to use 'new' with this expression?" https://tsplay.dev/W4gL1m

What good is an empty class? You can make a phantom property that TS believes exists but doesn't exist at runtime, as shown in this playground link, but I don't know if I've ever heard anyone with a use for a completely empty class. Does this fully address the question now?

@jcalz if you make the phantom property private, yes
